# python read file in certain format

Tags: python, numpy, text

I have files with a certain format as follows:

```
36.1 37.1 A: Hi, how are you?
39.1 40.1 B: I am ok!
```

I am using `numpy.loadtxt()` to read this file with `dtype = np.dtype([('start', '|S1'), ('end', 'f8'),('person','|S1'),('content','|S100')])`

The first 3 column is fine but the string part always has an issue: the format does not match. I guess it is because each speaker says variable length words. Does anyone know a better way to solve this?

many thanks,

Comment: Why would you use numpy to read text?

Comment: because I use numpy for the whole file. wanna try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the text manually without numpy and just iterating over the lines in the file.

```
with open("read.txt", "r") as infile:
    chats = []
    for i in infile:
        data = i.split(":")
        start, end, name, content = data[0].split(" ")[0], data[0].split(" ")[1], data[0].split(" ")[2], data[1].strip("\n")
        chats.append([start, end, name, content])
```

The file is opened and read line by line, while start, end, name and content is appended as a sublist to the list chats.

Answer (score 0):

In your file most columns are separated by white space, but so are the strings in the last field.  If instead you had ; or tab separating the fields, it would be easier.

But `genfromtxt` lets us specify field widths instead of delimiters,  Thus with your text sample I can do

```
In [912]: dt=np.dtype([('start', 'f8'), ('end', 'f8'),('person','|S3'),('content','|S100')])
In [913]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=dt,delimiter=[4,6,3,20])
Out[913]: 
array([( 36.1,  37.1, b'A: ', b'Hi, how are you?'),
       ( 39.1,  40.1, b'B: ', b'I am ok!')], 
      dtype=[('start', '<f8'), ('end', '<f8'), ('person', 'S3'), ('content', 'S100')])
```

---

`split` has a `maxsplit` parameter that might handy if you read the file yourself.

```
In [922]: alist = [tuple(line.split(maxsplit=3)) for line in txt.splitlines()]
In [923]: alist
Out[923]: 
[(b'36.1', b'37.1', b'A:', b'Hi, how are you?'),
 (b'39.1', b'40.1', b'B:', b'I am ok!')]
```

Note this is a list of tuples, which is easily converted to a structured array with your dtype:

```
In [924]: np.array(alist, dtype=dt)
Out[924]: 
array([( 36.1,  37.1, b'A:', b'Hi, how are you?'),
       ( 39.1,  40.1, b'B:', b'I am ok!')], 
      dtype=[('start', '<f8'), ('end', '<f8'), ('person', 'S3'), ('content', 'S100')])
```

---

For testing I used

```
In [900]: txt=b"""36.1 37.1 A: Hi, how are you?
     ...: 39.1 40.1 B: I am ok!
     ...: """
```

but you could read the file line by line or all at once and do the same thing.  `genfromtxt` works just as well with a file, or list of lines.

Another option is to read the file line by line, replace selected spaces with a desirable delimiter and pass it on to `genfromtxt`.

For example making a `;` delimited text (you already have `,` in the strings):

```
In [935]: alist = [b';'.join(line.split(maxsplit=3)) for line in txt.splitlines()]
In [936]: alist
Out[936]: [b'36.1;37.1;A:;Hi, how are you?', b'39.1;40.1;B:;I am ok!']
In [937]: np.genfromtxt(alist, delimiter=';', dtype=dt)
Out[937]: 
array([( 36.1,  37.1, b'A:', b'Hi, how are you?'),
       ( 39.1,  40.1, b'B:', b'I am ok!')], 
      dtype=[('start', '<f8'), ('end', '<f8'), ('person', 'S3'), ('content', 'S100')])
```